# Show the correct row number after sorting the DatagridView column [C# WinForm]

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a DataGridView where I am populating numerical data. I have also managed to write the code to show the Row number in the Row HeaderCell property. For this I am using the following code:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in datagridview.Rows)
       row.HeaderCell.Value = (row.Index + 1).ToString();
```

The Sorting ability of each column is also enabled and when I click on the Column HeaderCell, the data in that column arranges (sort) properly. But the issue is even after sorting the row number doesn't change to reflect the original unsorted data. For example:

When the data is loaded on the DataGridView it looks something like this:

```
  | Col1 | Col2
----------------
 1| 5    | num1
 2| 2    | num2
 3| 7    | num3
```

After I click on Col1 to sort the DataGridView looks like this:

```
  | Col1 >| Col2
----------------
 1| 2    | num2
 2| 5    | num1
 3| 7    | num3
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
  | Col1 >| Col2
----------------
 2| 2    | num2
 1| 5    | num1
 3| 7    | num3
```

Any idea how I can achieve this easily?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a field (rownumber) to your datasource.
After sorting you could do something like this.

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in datagridview.Rows)
   row.HeaderCell.Value = row["rownumber"].ToString();
```

Comment: This will work if: **1)** Do it in `DataBindingComplete`. **2)** Set `dataGridView1.Columns["rownumber"].Visible = false` **3)** Set `row.HeaderCell.Value = row.Cells["rownumber"].Value.ToString();`